# Creating a smoother curve for high order polynom fit

Tags: python, linear-regression

I am trying to visualise an over. and underfitting of data. It works fine but the high order polynom plotting has edges (due to too few points) but how can I feed it more points to predict for? i.e. create the model based on `x,y` but predict then for `x_fine` ...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures


np.random.seed(19824)

step = 0.1
x = np.arange(0, 3, step)   # start,stop,step
y = np.sin(x)
numEl = len(x)

noise_mu = 0
noise_sigma = 0.05
noise_x = np.random.normal(noise_mu, noise_sigma, numEl)
noise_y = np.random.normal(noise_mu, noise_sigma*2, numEl)

x = x + noise_x
y = y + noise_y
x = x.reshape(-1, 1)


# linar model
lm = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model = lm.fit(x, y)
predictions = lm.predict(x)
plt.plot(x, y, "ob", alpha=0.5, label="data")
plt.plot(x, predictions, color='black', linewidth=1, alpha=0.5)


# poly 30
step = 0.01
x_fine = np.arange(0, 3, step)
x_fine = x_fine.reshape(-1, 1)

degree = 30

polynomial_features= PolynomialFeatures(degree=degree)
x_poly = polynomial_features.fit_transform(x)

model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model.fit(x_poly, y)
y_poly_pred = model.predict(x_poly)

plt.plot(x, y_poly_pred, color='red', linewidth=1, alpha=0.5)


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the last lines of your code for these ones:

```py
model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model.fit(x_poly, y)

xx = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 1001)
xx_poly = polynomial_features.fit_transform(xx)
y_poly_pred = model.predict(xx_poly)

plt.plot(xx, y_poly_pred, color='red', linewidth=1, alpha=0.5)
plt.ylim(0, 1.5)

plt.show()
```

Then you obtain the smoother curve:
[image]

Note that fitting data with such a high degree polynomial can result in big spikes.